# Delete a specific file if this one is empty

Tags: file, batch-file, delete-file

I would like to delete a specific file if this one is empty by the use of a windows .bat file. Here is my non-working script:

```
if %~z1 == 0
echo %~z1===================
del "%1"
goto :eof
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if %~z1==0 (
echo %~z1===================
del "%1"
)
goto :eof
```

The `goto` should be placed inside the parentheses if you want to go to end-of-file having deleted the file. As I've placed it, in the absence of further information, the batch would terminate regardless.